# How to get a desired output using groupBy in dataweave?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I'm looking for an output similar to this one below where i want to groupBy costomer and orderid.

Input:

[
{
"item": 621,
"orderid": "ON22",
"qty": 45.0,
"customer": "610",
"date": "1988-08-13"
},
{
"item": 63,
"orderid": "ON2234",
"qty": 7,
"customer": "813",
"date": "2001-08-13"
}
]

Desired output:
[
{
"customer":"813",
"data":[
{
"item":63,
"qty":7,
"orderid":"ON2234",
"date":"2001-08-13"
}
]
},
{
"customer":"610",
"data":[
{
"item": 621,
"qty": 45.0,
"orderid": "ON22",
"date": "1988-08-13"
}
]
}
]

Comment: Are all values of customer expected to be equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply map the default output of your groupBy result since your output does not require any additional logic.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload groupBy $.customer pluck ((customerOrders, customerId) -> {
    customer: customerId as String,
    data: customerOrders
})
```

Comment: if i have this input : [
    {
        "item": 625,
        "orderid": "ON222723-JH",
        "qty": 45.0,
        "customer": "890",
        "date": "1990-08-13"
    },
    {
        "item": 618,
        "orderid": "ON222723-qa",
        "qty": 23.0,
        "customer": "870",
        "date": "1998-05-11"
    }
]

Comment: and i want this output:

Comment: and wants this output: [
{
  "customer": "890",
  "data": [
    {
      "item": 625,
      "orderid": "ON222723-JH",
      "qty": 45.0,
      "customer": "890",
      "date": "1990-08-13"
    }
  ]
  },
  {
  "customer": "870",
  "data": [
    {
      "item": 618,
      "orderid": "ON222723-qa",
      "qty": 23.0,
      "customer": "870",
      "date": "1998-05-11"
    }
  ]
}
]

Comment: That make sense, I was wondering that your expected output would not work with multiple customers. Can you update the output in your question. Or you can delete this and create a new one since the output is not possible with multiple and different customer IDs

Comment: @Bansal I have updated the question with new input as well desired output. thank you

Comment: Check the formatting. Use tripple back tick '`' for posting json

Comment: i have updated new  input and output. Im looking to group by 2 fields

Comment: Please raise a separate question and revert the changes you did here. You can not just keep updating input and outputs of the same question forever, especially after earlier one is resolved. Also take care of formatting as mentioned earlier.

Comment: I do apologize for misunderstanding of the procedures. I have updated it to the original post. Im going to post new request in a separate question @ Bansal